# WPF custom grid children not refresh on design view

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

My final goal is to simplify the writing of grid, especially the writing of `Grid.Row="x"` and `Grid.Column="y"`. To do that, I create a new class inherit from Grid, and override `theOnInitialized` method. This works fine, but only in runtime, not in the design view (The view in Visual Studio to edit XAML)

I try to override the `OnVisualChildrenChanged` method, but this method is call before the item initialization, so I can't get all item info I want. I try to record the item.Initialized event, but it is never call in design view.

The only way I found, but not a solution, is to add an useless item to the end of collection, and call the ChildUpdate function in `OnVisualChildrenChanged`. With this solution only the last item is not initialized, but not usefull. My goal is to reduce the code size, and the bug happen only for the design view.

example to reproduce:

```
    <local:CustomGrid x:Name="myGrid" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"/>
    </local:CustomGrid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace AtlantisUpdater
{
    class CustomGrid : Grid
    {
        protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
        {
            if (visualAdded != null)
                ((FrameworkElement)visualAdded).Initialized += CustomGrid_Initialized;

            if (visualRemoved != null)
                ((FrameworkElement)visualRemoved).Initialized -= CustomGrid_Initialized;

            //UpdateChildren();
            base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);
        }

        private void CustomGrid_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
                throw new Exception("My error");
            UpdateChildren();
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateChildren();
            base.OnInitialized(e);
        }

        protected void UpdateChildren()
        {
            int rowNb = RowDefinitions.Count;
            int columnNb = ColumnDefinitions.Count;
            if (columnNb == 0)
            {
                ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                columnNb = ColumnDefinitions.Count;
            }
            int nextRow = 0;
            int nextColumn = 0;
            foreach (UIElement child in Children)
            {
                //happens while editing the children collection in xaml
                //if we don't handle this, the Designer throws an exception
                if (child == null)
                    continue;

                string name = ((FrameworkElement)child).Name; // empty for the last child, when call from OnVisualChildrenChanged 
                if (nextRow >= RowDefinitions.Count)
                    RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

                bool rowIsDefined = child.ReadLocalValue(RowProperty) != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
                bool columnIsDefined = child.ReadLocalValue(ColumnProperty) != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
                if (rowIsDefined)
                {
                    for (int i = RowDefinitions.Count; i < GetRow(child) + 1; i++)
                        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                }
                if (!rowIsDefined && !columnIsDefined)
                {
                    SetRow(child, nextRow);
                    SetColumn(child, nextColumn);

                    nextColumn += GetColumnSpan(child);

                    if (nextColumn >= columnNb)
                    {
                        nextColumn = 0;
                        nextRow++;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in your `UpdateChildren` method. This method has `nextRow`, `nextColumn` as local variables and always set to `0`, and this method is called every time a visual child is initialized. So, all children get their `Row` and `Column` values as `0`.

You should make `nextRow` and `nextColumn` as class level fields, then this would work as expected.

```
class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    private int _nextRow = 0;
    private int _nextColumn = 0;

    protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
    {
        base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);
        UpdateChildren();
    }

    void UpdateChildren()
    {
        int rowNb = RowDefinitions.Count;
        int columnNb = ColumnDefinitions.Count;
        if (columnNb == 0)
        {
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star) });
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star) });
            columnNb = ColumnDefinitions.Count;
        }
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            //happens while editing the children collection in xaml
            //if we don't handle this, the Designer throws an exception
            if (child == null)
                continue;

            string name = ((FrameworkElement)child).Name; // empty for the last child, when call from OnVisualChildrenChanged 
            if (_nextRow >= RowDefinitions.Count)
                RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

            bool rowIsDefined = child.ReadLocalValue(RowProperty) != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            bool columnIsDefined = child.ReadLocalValue(ColumnProperty) != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            if (rowIsDefined)
            {
                for (int i = RowDefinitions.Count; i < GetRow(child) + 1; i++)
                    RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            }
            if (!rowIsDefined && !columnIsDefined)
            {
                SetRow(child, _nextRow);
                SetColumn(child, _nextColumn);

                _nextColumn += GetColumnSpan(child);

                if (_nextColumn >= columnNb)
                {
                    _nextColumn = 0;
                    _nextRow++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact your first reply was more close to what I expect. In your second reply, my main problem still exist : I can't get properties like child.Name and other custom properties